# React prevent form submission when enter is pressed inside input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React prevent form submission when enter is pressed

I have the following React Search Bar component where the parent container can call using

```
<SearchBar onInputChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Everytime the user changes the input, the parent container will be notified. This is why my search bar does not need any submit button.

However, I am finding that if I press enter inside my search bar, the whole page refreshes. And I dont want that.

I know if I have a button in the form, I could call event.preventDefault(). But in this case I have no button so I dont know what to do here

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { value: '' };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
        this.props.onInputChange(e.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div id="search-bar">
            <form>
            <FormGroup controlId="formBasicText">
                <FormControl
                type="text"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.value}
                placeholder="Enter Character Name"
                />          
            </FormGroup>
            </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchBar
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a form tag? If you replace that with a div then enter won't submit.

Comment: Div would word too. I had a form there just incase I want to add more fields in the future and form allows more control

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You need to create a form handler that would prevent the default form action.

The simplest implementation would be:

```
<form onSubmit={e => { e.preventDefault(); }}>
```

But ideally you create a dedicated handler for that:

```
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
```

with the following implementation

```
submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Is the second form more ideal for readability mostly? Or are there other reasons?

Comment: @TroyCosentino other reasons: in the first `e => { e.preventDefault(); }` this is an anonymous function which is recreated every render loop, so react replaces it in the child element. With a dedicated handler a function instance only created once and then left untouched.

Comment: Didn't work for me. What did work is ` onKeyPress={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault(); }}` on `<form>`.

Comment: @AviKaminetzky it's impossible `e.key === 'Enter'` condition could change anything in the behaviour. It's likely that you have some other problem there. Also I don't see how `onKeyPress` makes any sense for a form.

Answer (score 44):

In a React component with a Search input field, nested in a larger (non-React OR React) form, this worked best for me across browsers:

```
<MyInputWidget
  label="Find"
  placeholder="Search..."
  onChange={this.search}
  onKeyPress={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault(); }}
  value={this.state.searchText} />
```

`(e)=>{e.target.keyCode === 13}` (@DavidKamer's answer) is incorrect: You don't want the `event.target.` That's the input field. You want the event itself. And in React (specifically 16.8, at the moment), you want `event.key` (e.key, whatever you want to call it).

Comment: keypress is deprecated https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Comment: The React events list for keyboard events in v 17.0.1 are:

onKeyDown onKeyPress onKeyUp

See https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events

I don't know whether these are polyfilled to what's not deprecated. Haven't looked into that. But onKeyDown or onKeyUp should work fine for most usages, in my example above. --thanks

Comment: The answer by @zerkms did not work for me either but this solution works.
I've updated the prop from `onKeyPress` to `onKeyDown` since `onKeyPress` is deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

The best way to prevent the ENTER, as suggested also by Eon is to **add the following to your input element**:

```
onKeyPress={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault(); }}
```

Comment: keypress is deprecated https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if this works for every situation, as when you press enter in a form's input field you will still trigger the onSubmit method, although the default submit won't occur. This means that you will still trigger your pseudo submit action that you've designed for your form. A one liner with ES6 that solves the problem specifically and entirely:

```
<input onKeyPress={(e)=>{e.target.keyCode === 13 && e.preventDefault();}} />
```

This solution should have 0 side effects and solves the problem directly.

Comment: This is a good solution if there's only 1 input, handling it at the onSubmit level is better for a form with multiple controls

Comment: My solution works in many situations that would land someone here. Many people will try the above solution only to find that it prevents the enter key for every part of a form. More specific is better in situations where you want other functionality to continue as it would by default. **If you have a single input or component in a form that you don't want to trigger your submit function for, this is the only solution that will work**. Other methods will explicitly disable the enter button or will explicitly disable submitting with html5 standards, but will not do what is asked.

Comment: Thank you. Disabling submit for a single input out of several is exactly what I was looking to do.

Comment: For me e.target.keyCode turned up undefined, but e.key === 'Enter' works great.

Comment: keypress is deprecated https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event

Comment: `e.code === "Enter"` if you don't care about `IE`

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
<Input
   ...
   onKeyDown={(e) => { e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault() }}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

prevent for Enter key for search input:

```
<input type="text" onKeyDown={e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') e.preventDefault();
}} />
```

Comment: `onKeyPress` is deprecated, use `onKeyDown` instead.